# How can I do an update with case and select?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to assign an ID code by searching for the name.

```
update db.request r
set s.CreateByID = ( 
                select r.ID 
                from db.user u
                where r.NameCreateBy = u.Name
                )
where r.ID in (23506);
```

How would I put a case clause for when I can't find the name in the user table?

The request table has the correct name of the person who created the request. But the createByID column is returning a code referring to another user. So I need to update createByID based on the user ID, disregarding the value shown in the request table.

Comment: If you know `r.ID` in advance (because you're filtering on it), what's the purpose of having a `SET s.CreateByID = (SELECT r.ID FROM ...)`?

Comment: what table is `s.CreateByID` in?  did you mean `r.CreateByID`?

Comment: The request table has the correct name of the person who created the request. But the createByID column is returning a code referring to another user.  So I need to update createByID based on the user ID, disregarding the value shown in the request table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `COALESCE` if the subquery returns `NULL` amd set a value for example 0

```
update db.request r
set r.CreateByID = COALESCE(( 
                select u.ID 
                from db.user u
                where r.NameCreateBy = u.Name
                ),0)
where r.ID in (23506);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `JOIN` inside the `UPDATE` statement, if you need to match fields between two tables:

```
UPDATE     db.request r
INNER JOIN db.user    u ON r.NameCreateBy = u.Name AND r.ID IN (23506)
SET s.CreateByID = COALESCE(r.ID, <substitution_value>);
```